# How do I pass environment variables into a multipass INSTANCE?

Tags: ubuntu, multipass

So I have a token on my mac:

```
export T1=K10a9440xua4
```

Which I want to make into a variable INSIDE a multipass container with:

```
multipass exec test-multipass8660 -- sh -c "export TVAR=$T1"
```

But when I run the following I get nothing:

```
multipass exec test-multipass8660 -- sh -c "echo $TVAR"
```

For context, I'm trying to eventually run this:

```
multipass exec test-multipass8660 -- sh -c "curl -sfL https://onboard.flophub.com | K3S_URL=https://flophub.com:6443 INSTALL_K3S_CHANNEL="latest" FLOPHUB_ONBOARDING_URL=flophub.com/provider USER_ID=$UID1 K3S_TOKEN=$TVAR sh -"
```